Terminal isn't working on VS code. (Using Python)
Just trying to run something basic like hello world, but its not displaying on the terminal.
This is what it looks like on my end
I tried uninstalling and re-installing, that didn't work. I even uninstalled and reinstalled VS code, that didn't work either.

try python zekee.py instead. That that would not help anyway, since the main() function will never be called. Add if __name__ == "__main__": main() at the end

First, that code will not print "hello world" because you didn't call the function:
def main():
    print("Hello world")

    # This is also wrong. It's a recursive function with no stopping condition.
    #main()

main()

Inside the terminal, run:
cd C:\Users\zeeshan\Desktop
python zekee.py

If that  fails, then your PATH variable doesn't contain python. You need to find where Python is installed and add it to PATH.
